# How to arrange filters in specific order javascript/reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am currently using reactJS for creating front-end components.
Object is

```
{
    "name": "result",
    "entity":  {
            "demand": ["60", "70"],
            "supply": ["monaco"],
            "country": ["USA", "China"],
            "provider": ["TMX", "DataTech"]

}
```

Here I want to show entity as filters in the dashboard. Values of entity can be country, supply, provider, demand. Now If the provider entity is not present then it will not appear in filters of the dashboard. In response, the entity can be any order(no specific order).

I have to show filters on my dashboard in some order. The order has to be

```
   country, supply, provider, demand
```

I did something like this. It shows filters not in the order which I've specified

```
let array = Object.keys(this.state.response.entity);
    if (array.length > 0) {
      return array.map((key, index) => {
        let newObj = {};
        let newArray = [];

          let dataCol = array[key];
          if (dataCol !== undefined) {
            if (Array.isArray(dataCol)) {
              for (let j = 0; j < dataCol.length; j++) {
                let object = {};
                  object.value = dataCol[j];
                  newArray.push(object);
              }
              newObj[key] = newArray;
            }
          }
        }
      }
```

How to achieve this ordering?

This are the filters with some dropdown values. So the order has to be something like this:

country
supply
provider
demand

Comment: what is the expected result, post the complete object

Comment: This should be more or less what you're looking for: https://jsfiddle.net/6qp9drcm/ (the idea is to create an array of keys in the right order, then filter and map it according to `entity`'s properties)